# Mysql join query on three tables with multiple columns

Tags: mysql, join, relational-database

I have three tables like this:

**Specialisation**

```
sid | s_name
--------------
 1  | test 1
 2  | test 2
```

**Person**

```
pid | name | sid
------------------
 1  | ABC  |  1
 2  | XYZ  |  2
```

**Timing**

```
tid | time_from | time_to  | pid
----------------------------------
 1  | 08:00:00  | 10:00:00 |  1
 2  | 20:00:00  | 22:00:00 |  1
 3  | 09:00:00  | 14:00:00 |  2
 4  | 19:00:00  | 20:00:00 |  2
```

**I want to get result something like this*

```
pid | name | s_name | time_from  | time_to
--------------------------------------------
 1  | ABC  | test 1 | 08:00:00   | 10:00:00
```

Description:
All three tables are connected.
I want all records where
**specialisation** id = '1'
**person** name **Like** 'ABC'
**timing** is in between '08:00:00' and '10:00:00'. 
 
I tried several combinations of mysql joins but not able to fetch the data correctly.

Comment: what is the data time `time_from` and `time_to`?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use `INNER JOIN` for this,

```
SELECT  a.pid, a.name,
        b.sname,
        c.time_from,
        c.time_to
FROM    person a
        INNER JOIN specialisation b
            ON a.sid = b.sid
        INNER JOIN Timing c
            ON a.pid = c.pid
WHERE   a.sid = 1 and 
        a.name='ABC'  AND 
        c.time_from >= '08:00:00' AND c.time_to <= '10:00:00'
```

- [**SQLFiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3ea7e/4)

Comment: @AnandPhadke they both perform the same since we are both using `INNER JOIN`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Simple Join like this

```
     Select P.pid , name , s_name ,time_from ,
     time_to from Specialisation S 
     Join Person P on P.sid=S.sid 
     Join Timing T on T.pid= P.pid 
     where T.time_from >= '08:00:00' AND T.time_to <='10:00:00' And P.name='ABC';
```

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3ea7e/32)

Answer (score 0):

This is a straight forward `JOIN` with appropriate `WHERE` condition.

```
 SELECT t.pid, p.name, s.s_name, t.time_from, t.time_to 
 FROM   Timing AS t
 JOIN   Person AS p ON p.pid = t.pid
 JOIN   Specialisation AS s ON s.sid = p.sid
 WHERE  s.sid = 1
    AND t.time_from >= 08:00:00 AND t.time_to <= 10:00:00
```

This is a simple condition where you have to use `JOIN`s to fetch data this way. Its so simple that you will get a hang of it right after your first use. May be this question and answers will help you understand it.

Comment: Why downvote? :o. If not the perfect answer, doesn't this guide OP to right direction? And pretty much all the answers that came after uses the same ditto code!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT p.pid, p.name, s.s_name, t.time_from, t.time_to 
FROM   Timing AS t
JOIN   Person AS p ON p.pid = t.pid
JOIN   specialisation AS s ON s.sid = p.sid
WHERE  s.sid = 1 and p.name='ABC'
AND t.time_from >= '08:00:00' AND t.time_to <= '10:00:00'
```

Comment: `pid` will be ambiguous to select use alias @AnandPhadke

Comment: Thangs-Thanks for poining out this

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT B.PID pid, B.NAME name, A.SNAME s_name, C.TIME_FROM time_from, C.TIME_TO time_to
FROM SPECIALISATION A, PERSON B, TIMING C
WHERE A.SID = 1 AND A.SID=B.SID AND B.PID=C.PID 
AND C.TIME_FROM >=08:00:00 AND C.TIME_TO <=10.00.00
```

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
    SELECT t.pid, p.name, s.s_name, t.time_from, t.time_to 
     FROM   Specialisation AS s
    left join  Person AS p ON p.sid = s.sid
    left join  Timing AS t ON t.pid = p.pid
    WHERE  s.sid = 1
        AND t.time_from >= 08:00:00' AND t.time_to <= 10:00:00
group by t.tid
```