# How Mysql join query on three tables with multiple colums that fetch only one id

Tags: mysql

I have three tables like this:

**Student**

```
stuNum | stuName
------------------
2012   | jack 
2013   | tom
```

**Quiz**

```
quizNum | quizName
------------------
1       | chapter 1
2       | chapter 2
3       | chapter 3
```

**studentassessment**

```
stuNum | quizNum | assessmentMark
-----------------------------------
2012   | 1       | 10
2012   | 2       | 8
2012   | 3       | 10
2013   | 1       | 5
```

I want to get result something like this

```
stuNum | stuName | Quiz Num | assessmentMark
--------------------------------------------
2012   | jack    | 1        | 10
2012   | jack    | 2        | 8
2012   | jack    | 3        | 10
```

description : all three table are connected.. i want to get the stuNum=2012, quizNum that all stuNum have done.

I tried several combination to fetch result but can't work.
this is example combination that i tried :

```
$sql = "select a.stuNum,a.quizNum,a.assessmentMark from studentassessment a inner join student b on a.stuNum=b.stuNum inner join quiz c on a.quizNum=c.quizNum where b.stuNum='2012'"
```

Comment: look like your question similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13302898/mysql-join-query-on-three-tables-with-multiple-colums

Comment: c.quizName instead of a.quizName, you should be good or if you want num, then a.quizNum

Comment: not really similar because that question already set the value..for this question, i can't get the quizNum value for stuNum=2012

Comment: sorry,im beginner in sql T__T

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Query**

```
SELECT a.stuNum,
b.stuName,
a.quizNum,
c.quizName,
a.assessmentMark
FROM studentAssessment a
JOIN student b
ON a.stuNum=b.stuNum
JOIN quiz c
ON a.quizNum=c.quizNum
WHERE a.stuNum=2012;
```

**Output**

```
+--------+---------+---------+-----------+----------------+
| STUNUM | STUNAME | QUIZNUM |  QUIZNAME | ASSESSMENTMARK |
+--------+---------+---------+-----------+----------------+
|   2012 |    Jack |       1 | chapter 1 |             10 |
|   2012 |    Jack |       2 | chapter 2 |              8 |
|   2012 |    Jack |       3 | chapter 3 |             10 |
+--------+---------+---------+-----------+----------------+
```

**[Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/97e24b/6)**

Comment: Welcome. If this solved your problem, please mark it as answer

Answer (score 0):

Here .. try this out

```
SELECT a.stuNum,b.stuName, a.quizNum, a.assessmentMark 
FROM studentassessment a 
INNER JOIN student b ON a.stuNum = b.stuNum 
WHERE b.stuNum='2012'
```

you do not need to put an inner join on quiz table since neither you are retrieving any value from it nor you are using it to deduce some relation in your output